# Perl - Extract string from text block

Tags: regex, string, perl, extract, matching

I have some text like this which is stored in a variable:

```
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20201014084217
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001225208-20-012454
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  4
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20201012
FILED AS OF DATE:       20201014
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20201014
```

What I need is to search the string, and extract this line:

> ACCESSION NUMBER:     0001225208-20-012454

And, more specifically, the number:  0001225208-20-012454, without the dashes.

Can't seem to find the right syntax:

```
my $access_no = $txt =~ /ACCESSION NUMBER/m;
```

That is not working.

Comment: Regex `()` grouping and list context for left part of the assignment does the job. `my ($access_no) = $txt =~ /ACCESSION NUMBER: \s+ (\S+) /x;` (`\s` could be replaced with `\h` to consider only horizontal white spaces)

Comment: Or with a little different approach `my $access_no = $1 if $txt =~ /ACCESSION NUMBER:\s+(.*)$/m;`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing it. One way would be:

```
my $access_no = ''; 
$access_no = $1 . $2 . $3 if $txt =~ m/ACCESSION NUMBER:\s+(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which parses the entire string into an appropriate data structure (hash), and then changes the desired hash element. This method is longer than the one by *l4chsalter*, but is potentially easier to maintain and extend, in case you need the rest of the fields as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my $txt = <<'EOF';
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20201014084217
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001225208-20-012454
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  4
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20201012
FILED AS OF DATE:       20201014
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20201014
EOF

# Parse the entire string into the hash with keys/values:
my %val = $txt =~ m{ ^ ( [^:\n]+ ): \s+ ( \S+ .*? ) $ }gxms;

# Print the hash with the parsed string (optional):
# say "'$_' => '$val{$_}'" for keys %val;

# Remove non-digits from the desired element:
$val{'ACCESSION NUMBER'} =~ tr/0-9//cd;

say $val{'ACCESSION NUMBER'};
# 000122520820012454
```

`my %val = $txt =~ m{ ^ ( [^:\n]+ ): \s+ ( \S+ .*? ) $ }gxms;` : Capture the patterns in parenthesis, return them as a LIST and assign the list to the hash `%val`. Its keys will be the field names and values - the corresponding field values.

The regex uses these modifiers: `/g` to return multiple matches, `/x` to disregard whitespace and comments inside the regex for readability, `/m` to match across multiple lines, and `/s` to make `.` match a newline (optional, not used here, but I like to have it in complex regexes for maintainability).

`^ ( [^:\n]+ ):` matches any characters, starting at the beginning of the line (`^`), that is not a colon or newline, repeated 1 or more times, until the first colon. The parentheses thus capture the field name.

`( \S+ .*? ) $` matches the non-whitespace character followed by any characters 0 or more times until the first end of the line (`$`). The parentheses thus capture the field value.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to extract data of interest and to manipulate them.

Bellow is a code for *simple approach*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $num = $1 if $data =~ /ACCESSION NUMBER:\s+(.*)$/m;

say 'Extracted: ' . $num;
$num =~ s/-//g;
say 'Processed: ' . $num;

__DATA__
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20201014084217
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001225208-20-012454
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  4
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20201012
FILED AS OF DATE:       20201014
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20201014
```

Output

```
Extracted: 0001225208-20-012454
Processed: 000122520820012454
```

And now more *complicated approach* to extract event record into data structure for further manipulation

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my %event  = $data =~ /<(.*?)>(.*)$/m;
my %record = $data =~ /(.*?):\s+(.*)$/gm;

$event{record} = \%record;

say '--- Read record '        . '-' x 29;
say $data;
say '--- Content of %record ' . '-' x 22;
say Dumper(\%record);
say '--- Content of %event '  . '-' x 23;
say Dumper(\%event);
say '-' x 45;

my $num0 = $record{'ACCESSION NUMBER'};
my $num1 = $num0;
my $num2 = $num0;
my $num3 = $num0;
my @parts = split '-', $num0;

$num1 =~ s/-//g;
$num2 =~ s/\D//g;
$num3 =~ tr/-//d;

say '$num0 = ' . $num0;
say '$num1 = ' . $num1;
say '$num2 = ' . $num2;
say '$num3 = ' . $num3;
say '@parts = ' . join '', @parts;

__DATA__
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20201014084217
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001225208-20-012454
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  4
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20201012
FILED AS OF DATE:       20201014
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20201014
```

Output

```
--- Read record -----------------------------
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20201014084217
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001225208-20-012454
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  4
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20201012
FILED AS OF DATE:       20201014
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20201014
--- Content of %record ----------------------
$VAR1 = {
          'FILED AS OF DATE' => '20201014',
          'CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT' => '20201012',
          'CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE' => '4',
          'ACCESSION NUMBER' => '0001225208-20-012454',
          'PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT' => '1',
          'DATE AS OF CHANGE' => '20201014'
        };

--- Content of %event -----------------------
$VAR1 = {
          'record' => {
                        'FILED AS OF DATE' => '20201014',
                        'CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT' => '20201012',
                        'CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE' => '4',
                        'ACCESSION NUMBER' => '0001225208-20-012454',
                        'PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT' => '1',
                        'DATE AS OF CHANGE' => '20201014'
                      },
          'ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME' => '20201014084217'
        };

---------------------------------------------
$num0 = 0001225208-20-012454
$num1 = 000122520820012454
$num2 = 000122520820012454
$num3 = 000122520820012454
@parts = 000122520820012454
```